# Visual studio 2013, can't open or create projects

Tags: project, visual-studio-2013, vcproj

I tried getting Visual Studio 2013 to work today but i couldn't get it to work. This is the error I keep getting when making a c++ window application.

The error message I keep getting:

[image]

I tried opening the vcxproj file in the message box, but I couldn't open that either. In fact I am unable to open any vcxproject's. This problem happens with pretty much all languages.

I uninstalled vs 2012 and 2010, and then installed vs2013.

I have tried :

1. reinstalling the nuget extension.
2. Reinstalling vs2013 a bunch of time and trying to repair the
   installation
3. Uninstalling all traces of vs2010 and vs2012

one thing that might be important is that I used the november CTP c++ preview compiler for vs2012. I can't seem to uninstall it though

but nothing helped so far. Anybody able to help me?

Comment: CTP's are lethal.  The uninstaller is always the last thing they get reliable, just before RTM.  So they screw up the registry and convince the RTM installer that a component doesn't have to be installed because it is already present.  Getting your registry cleaned up is very difficult, there's usually a beta cleanup tool but I don't see one for 2013.  The only real hope you have is a restore point.  A bit late for that now you've made heavy changes to the machine by uninstalling 2010 and 2012.

Comment: No, I definitely don't have a restore point, and I installed the CTP months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to bite the bullet and re-install windows 7. Everything works again. In the future I will probably avoid downloading CTP's though or be very careful about uninstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed .NET framework 3.5 manually to install "SQL Server Management Studio" as I recall, Then I found that v. 3.5 is incompatible with VS 2013 as this page mentioned:
[VS 2013 Comparability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh266747%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

after I turned the related feature off, The problem with creating c++ projects disappeared ..